# Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 cannot connect to LG FH2 speaker since there's a Bluetooth profile incompatibility

Tags: xiaomi, 8.1-oreo, miui, bluetooth-audio, miui-10

I have found that my LG FH2 speaker uses the A2DP profile protocol:
http://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=gQHBfK7s0ZXFVKL7CatPeA

...whereas my Android phone is unable to get connected to it, since it has a different profile AVRCP:
https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services

Please note I am not trying to make my phone an audio sink, only audio gateway is totally fine for me.

*¿How can I install, push, hack, or sideload via ADB such an **A2DP** Bluetooth profile so I can connect my mobile to my speaker?*

Edit: it's a Redmi Note 5 global version (model M1803E7SH Latin America)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bluetooth profiles are an integral part of the Android system installed on your device (like a driver). Therefore usually you can't "install" or "update" the Bluetooth profiles.

Therefore you have only two possibilities:

1. Buy a different speaker that supports a Bluetooth profile your phone supports.
2. Search the Internet if there is a different ROM available for your phone that has A2DP support.